# RAM won't fit in a Toshiba Satellite C855

Tags: laptop, memory, hardware-failure

I have a Toshiba Satellite C855  with two RAM slots and one 4GB Ram.

I bought a new RAM but it will not fit in slot 2. I took out the old RAM from the slot 1 and put the new one and it fits without a problem. Both the old and the new RAM will not fit in the slot 2 though. I tried with 30 degree angle as well.

I am afraid to push the RAM with a lot of force because I might ruin it.

Here is a photo of my RAM slots with one RAM installed.

[image]

**EDIT**
Here is a photo with the RAM place in the socket. I can not push the RAM more "inside".

[image]

Comment: The Laptop is Toshiba Satellite C855x I am not sure about the model of the RAM(it is a Kingstone DDR3) but it fits in the slot 1 (and the computer is working without a problem), but it does not fit in the slot 2.

Comment: So since it fits in the slot 1 and works without a problem the RAM should be correct.

Comment: Add photo with not fitting, but placed in socket module.

Comment: @mmv-ru I have uploaded a photo with the RAM in the socket module.

Comment: Look normal. Keying match. First insertion require more force. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in used SO-DIMM socket, module slide in place (in up direction on photo) almost itself by own weight.

For new socket, some reasonable insertion force must be applied (about 4 kg) in up (related to photo direction) in 30 degree until it fit in socket and then easy push it down to click.

As example, look how deep inserted module fits in socket.

Don't push it down with force to make it parallel to board and click before it go up in socket!

Sometimes necessary manually open latches to click module in place.

Comment: I pushed with much more force and it went inside, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Normally ram in laptops is slotted in, at around a 35-45 degree angle, and then it'll 'click' down into place - on the second slot this angle can change hugely too - so just try wiggling the ram in place gently to see if you can see a way it'll fit and then click down into place.

Comment: Tried it but I cannot make it fit. I uploaded a new photo that better shows the problem I have. Please take a look at it.